# SQLite Support in windows phone cordova

Tags: windows, sqlite, cordova

I have a hybrid app and want to publish my app in both windows and android. My App works offline as well, hence I have used sqlite in it. The app works perfectly in android, but in windows sqlite is not supported. I tried https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql plugin but its not working. Anyone has faced this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=cordova-plugin-websql&platforms=cordova-android) website by cordova to search and see which platforms supports the plugins. [This](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) is the sqlite plugin supported by android,windows and ios

Comment: Thank you @Samal! Will try it out.